# Shift + in protractor

Tags: protractor, hotkeys

I have to test clicking on "Shift" key and the "+" key in the keyboard (not in the number part of the keyboard as this doesn't work (so I can only use the + key that is above the = key)
I tried everything I could think of, but couldn't get it working. I'm also using async/await. Any idea?

```
await this.placeholderElement.keyDown(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.SHIFT, "+")).perform();
await this.placeholderElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.SHIFT, "+"));
 await this.placeholderElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.SHIFT, protractor.Key.EQUALS));
 await this.placeholderElement.keyDown(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.SHIFT, protractor.Key.EQUALS)).perform();
```

And then one after the other:

```
        await this.placeholderElement.sendKey(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform();
        await this.placeholderElement.sendKey(protractor.Key.EQUALS).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the issue was the element I was sending sendKeys to wasn't interactable. What worked in the end was:

```
await this.editableEmptyDivP.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.SHIFT,protractor.Key.EQUALS));
```